# How to make consistent "top margin" of TOC and its continued page?

Tags: table-of-contents

The top margin of the 1st page of TOC and its continued page is not consistent. The same thing happens to Summary, List of Tables and List of Abbreviations.

I use a thesis template. The template can be download here: http://www.math.uic.edu/graduate/current/uicthesi

I think the uicthesi.cls file corresponds format parameters. I copy and paste the part that I think for this issue below. But no matter how I fix, the continued page of TOC (and summary, and List of Tables) still looks much higher than its 1st page.

Any comments are much appreciated!

```
\def\tableofcontents{
   \clearpage
   \typeout{TABLE OF CONTENTS.}
   \def\headmark{\vbox{
        \hbox to \textwidth{\bfseries\large\hfil TABLE OF CONTENTS
           (Continued) \hfil}
    \setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
        \vspace{\innerheadskip}
        \hbox to \textwidth{\bfseries\normalsize
           \underbar{CHAPTER}\hfil\underbar{PAGE}}}}
     \pagestyle{continued}
   \table@of@cont
   \newpage
   }

\def\table@of@cont{%
   \begin{singlespace}
   \thispagestyle{pageonbottom}
   \@makeschapterhead{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
   \par
   \hbox to \textwidth{\bfseries\underbar{CHAPTER}
       \hfil\underbar{PAGE}}
   \@starttoc{toc}
   \end{singlespace}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A quick hint: if you indent sample LaTeX code by 4 spaces, the site will pretty-print the code for you automatically. Separately, when posting code, it's usually a good idea to post a full "minimum working example" (MWE), rather than just some excerpts, to directly illustrate the problem you're trying to address.

Comment: You can also select the part you want 'code-highlighting' on, and then press the `{}` button above the answer box.

Comment: \def\@makeprelimhead{
   \def\headmark{\vbox{
        \hbox to \textwidth{\bfseries\large\hfil\section@mark{}
         (Continued) \hfil}}}
   \pagestyle{continued}
   \thispagestyle{pageonbottom}
   \@makeschapterhead{\section@mark}
   \par}

Comment: Above macro is defined for summary, table of abbreviations. I think it is this macro makes their continued page with less top margin.

Answer (score 2):

Because you gave us no MWE I checked the given link and found there a test file `uictest.tex`.  I added package `showframe` and compiled it.

There are 12 errors with my MiKTeX 2.9 (problems with `table` and `figure`), but I got an resulting pdf file.  There I can't see different top margins as you said.

The class is very old (`1996/01/31 v1.2`), gives a lot of errors and warnings with the official test page and should therefore be rewritten ...
Please write a bug report to the supporting people for this template.